# What should I do to see if the website user will browse is blocked or no? (javascript or html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a video on youtube but it cannot be viewed in some countries because access to youtube has been blocked in those countries. So, what would be your suggestion? i know i can put another link in html and ask the clients to click that link but i would like to know

1. Is there any way instead of putting 2 links ,something like putting 1 link that points to youtube and if the user cannot see the video there ( because access is blocked) , the user will automatically direct to another website or
2. just put the video on the server and ask the users to download it?
3. if none of proposed solutions is great , what is your idea?
4. is there any Javascript code for this

Also,  If I host it on my website, i will increase the size of my page.So, does it have any effect on the estimated time to view the page by users?

How can I do it in html4? i know we can emded video file in html 5 but what should I do for earlier versions?
Thank you all,

Comment: Don't re-post the same question if your original question is not answered to your satisfaction. Edit the original question instead.

Comment: I would include the Youtube video and a link to download the video.

Comment: If the blocked users really want to see they will use a proxy :)

Comment: Host the video yourself, and use something like the VideoJS http://www.videojs.com/ framework to play in HTML5 with Flash fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

Examine the YouTube website and find some JavaScript file there, and examine the JavaScript code to find some global variable it sets or changes.  Hopefully you can find a JavaScript file that has no side-effects on your web page.

Add it as a `<script ...>` in your page.

Write some JavaScript of your own that checks this global variable, which will tell you whether or not the YouTube JavaScript was loaded, which will tell you whether or not YouTube is blocked

Alternatively, you can do something similar with a CSS file from YouTube.

Comment: I hosted the videos on our company 's server.